# Memory error uninitialised values with strtol

Tags: c

Hello I have made a test program in order to get help on how to fix my problem when I use `valgrind --track-origins=yes -v ./a.out` on the following code it returns the following error;

```
==13192== 1 errors in context 1 of 1:
==13192== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==13192==    at 0x4E6CEA6: ____strtol_l_internal (strtol_l.c:438)
==13192==    by 0x4005EB: main (in Desktop/a.out)
==13192==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==13192==    at 0x40057D: main (in Desktop/a.out)
```

here is my code for the test program.

```
char newid[2];
char copyfromid[5] = "12345";

char *test, *extra;
int j, i = 0;

int outputNum;

for (j = 3; j < 5; j++) {
    newid[i] = copyfromid[j];
    i++;
}
test = newid;
outputNum = strtol(test, &extra, 10);
printf("%d", outputNum);
```

it is just a test program to turn the last two characters from the `copyfromid` into a number for a larger project that im working on, any help would be useful, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
  for (j=3;j<5;j++){
        newid[i] = copyfromid[j];
        i++;
    }
newid [i] =0;
```

You didn't add the trailing zero and newid must be at least 3 char long

Comment: `newid[2];` is too small for `newid [i] =0;`

Comment: `newid must be at least 3 char long` have you missed it @chux?

Comment: Fair enough - I did miss it.  Code speaks louder than  text.  Indicating the need for the larger array in the code would add clarity.  Just like `newid [i] =0;` was posted and not only  "You didn't add the trailing zero ".

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems in the code:

- you initialize a `char` array of size `5` with a 5 byte string. There is no space for the null terminator, the code generated does not make `copyfromid` a proper string.
- you copy 2 bytes from `copyfromid` into `newid` but do not null terminate `newid`, which is too short anyway. Calling `strtol()` on an invalid string has undefined behavior, which may explain your observations.

You could correct and simplify the code this way:

```
char copyfromid[] = "12345";
int outputNum = strtol(copyfromid + 2, NULL, 10);
printf("%d", outputNum);
```

Comment: Yes agree `strtol(test, ...)` is UB,  the prior code, itself,  is not UB.

Answer (score 1):

With `strtol(s, ...)`, `s` must point to a *string*.  `newid[]` lacks a *null character* so it is not a *string*.  This results in *undefined behavior*, (UB).

```
char newid[2];
char *test, *extra;
int j, i = 0;
for (j = 3; j < 5; j++) {
    newid[i] = ...;
    i++;
}
test = newid;
outputNum = strtol(test, &extra, 10);  // ** UB ** , newid is not a string
```

OP's error message hints that `strtol()` is attempting to walk passed the end of `newid[]` as it looks for a null character to stop.

> Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
>   ==13192==    at 0x4E6CEA6: ____strtol_l_internal (strtol_l.c:438)"

---

If code must use a 2 character `newid[2]` lacking a null character, code can use the below.  The 2 limits scanning up to 2 characters.

```
sscanf(newid, "%2d", &outputNum)
```

---

A simple good solution sticking with *strings* is as answered by [@chqrlie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46373588/2410359)

```
char copyfromid[] = "12345";
outputNum = strtol(copyfromid + 2, NULL, 10);
```